# While checking man file in youtube-dl

Tags: youtube, gnome-terminal, manpage, ubuntu-16.04, youtube-dl

Commend: `man youtube-dl`

Output :

```
No manual entry for youtube-dl
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation of youtube-dl does not include a manpage. There are a couple of options you can take:

- Read the information [online](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md)
- Contact your packaging and ask for a fixed package. If you have manually installed youtube-dl, this does not apply.
- Check out repository or build tarball and install youtube-dl manually from that with `sudo python setup.py install`.
- Install the manpage from a build - it's the `youtube-dl.1` file included in builds, and belongs in `/usr/share/man/man1/`.
- Create the manpage yourself by checking out the source code and running `make youtube-dl.1` . Place this file in `/usr/share/man/man1/`.
- Simply run `youtube-dl --help | less` - that's got most of the information anyways.
- Check out the youtube-dl repository (or a tarball) and run `less README.md` (you can also use any editor to open README.md)